# Navigating JSON Tree in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

Simple python student, simple python question. While (attempting to) navigate a JSON request with Python, I realized I was completely unaware of how to navigate multiple parents. **My goal is to call get_part, which first grabs data from an API in JSON format, and then separates the value *GHI* as a string from it.**

My current (simplified) code is:

```
def get_part():
  response = requests.get("APIUrlHere.com")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  output = str(json_data["groupOne"][2]["value"])
```

The API is in the format:

```
{
  "status": {
    "status": "Running",
  },
  "groupOne": {
    "one": {
      "value": "ABC",
    },
    "two": {
      "value": "DEF",
    },
    "thr": {
      "value": "GHI",
    }
  }
}
```

Attempting to run this code as is gives me an error message "KeyError: 0". What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: `groupOne` is not a list, it's a dictionary that happens to have keys with name of number, you need `['two']`.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, the correct json traversal would be "groupOne" --> "two" --> "value" but you replaced the "two" with 2. Try replacing 2 with "two" and seeing if it works.